# Counting the number of a specific word inside a php string

Tags: php, regex

I have a php string like as follows :

```
 $string = 'www absjdjjd www123 dkkd www wwww ghy ww';
```

How to count the no. of words just only "www" present in this string.There are two words in this string so result should be 2.
I have tried something like below but not working.

```
$val = 'www';
$count = substr_count($string, $val);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you

**Details:** used `explode` function to convert string into `array` and finally used `loop` with `condition`

```
<?php
    $string = 'www absjdjjd www123 dkkd www wwww ghy ww';
    $a=explode(" ",$string);
    print_r($a);
    $count=0;
    foreach($a as $value)
    {
        if($value=="www")
        {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    print_r($count);
    ?>
```

[sandbox output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/48c467e181b2cbb2f939890cbfcbc0192fa0f620)

Comment: A [slight variation](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c52dff1f8b7a10bb0eac91f720aac342e6b1ef9)

Answer (score 0):

With regex, which is faster and uses less memory then exploding, looping and counting:

```
<?php
$string = 'www absjdjjd www123 dkkd www wwww ghy ww';
echo preg_match_all('/\bwww\b/', $string, $matches); // 2
```

Comment: what about if the string is :   absjdjjd www dkkd www123 wwww

Answer (score 0):

Using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

```
<?php
$string = 'www absjdjjd www123 dkkd www wwww ghy ww';

$arr = array_count_values(explode(" ", $string));

echo isset($arr['www']) ? $arr['www'] : 0; //2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match www, you could use `\bwww\b` which will look for `www` between word boundaries `\b` with [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$string = 'www absjdjjd www123 dkkd www wwww ghy ww';
preg_match_all('/\bwww\b/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Will result in:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
  array(2) {
        [0]=>
    string(3) "www"
        [1]=>
    string(3) "www"
  }
}
```